# How can CMake 3.4.1 or greater be installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: cmake

I have attempted to install a current version of CMake on Ubuntu 15.10, but this has resulted in only version 3.4.1 being installed.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

How could version 3.4.3 or higher be installed?

Answer (score 3):

As 15.10 will be End of Life in a few short weeks, so you should upgrade to 16.04, which includes CMake 3.5.1 already.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 15.10** : It's fairly easy to build a new package cmake-3.5.1 : 1) Add two lines → `deb-src http://[url]/ubuntu/ xenial main` and 
`deb-src http://[url]/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` , and do : `sudo apt-get update`

2) `sudo apt-get build-dep cmake` , `sudo apt-get install fakeroot` ... and update to a couple of 16.04 packages : Download debhelper_9.20160115ubuntu3_all.deb, dh-strip-nondeterminism_0.015-1_all.deb, 
libarchive-zip-perl_1.56-2_all.deb, libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl_0.015-1_all.deb , and install with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

3) apt-get will automatically download the sources and build the five cmake packages in /home/name/folder/ with this command : `apt-get -b source cmake=5.3.1-1ubuntu1` .... Result : cmake_3.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb, 
cmake-curses-gui_3.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb,  cmake-data_3.5.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb, cmake-doc_3.5.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb, cmake-qt-gui_3.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

You can get a copy here : `cmake` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNcWkxdFNob0xkbW8/view?usp=sharing ... and `cmake-data` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNaURhR3lYY2tjaFU/view?usp=sharing